# Can people do Sandwich Attack (MEV) on Polygon?

Tags: polygon, mev

Can people do Sandwich Attack (MEV) on Polygon?
I know that people use Flashbots to do MEV on ETH layer 1. But Flashbots is not available on L2 or other side chains. Can people actually do similar attacks? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

[image: frontrun]

I see them sandwich attacks on polygon all the time!

Answer (score 0):

Sandwich (and frontrun) attacks existed also before MEV became possible. It was just a lot harder.

The way you do it is simply by manipulating your transaction's gas settings. Then you monitor the mempool and recent blocks and try to guess if your transaction gets in the desired spot or not. If not, you can try to either cancel it (higher fee with dummy tx contents) or simply increase the fee to try to get it in the right place. This is a very crude and inefficient way, but was better than nothing.

As far as I know, there is no real MEV in Polygon, and therefore only 'old fashioned' attacks are possible.

Comment: There have been a couple of 100+ long reorgs on Polygon that are likely connect to some MEV strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, validators could monitor the mempool and place their transactions around those that they wanna sandwich.
Likewise, searchers could partner with those powerful validators to rent their block space against a bribe. It's quite similar to Flashbots on Ethereum as you mentioned it, but these are private deals.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that they can. Because if they would be able to do that they would use it there and someone would have spread it.

You know what I mean?

Greetings ~Shadow